# export azure service bus configuration export

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-deployment, azure-configuration

I'm about to use Azure Service Bus and I'm going to have at least 4 environments that will be used for different parts of the development process, i.e. Build, Test, more Testing, and finally Production.

I would like to export my set of Queues and Topics from my namespace(s) and deploy them to other environments.

Does Azure offer a way of doing this, or do I need to create something myself?

Comment: Maybe you should try "Azure Resource Manager" (I need to try too ;))

Comment: i've looked at Azure Resource Manager. It goes as far as the namespace, but doesn't seem to include any detail around queues, topics, and relays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Resource Manager to create a template to deploy your namespace with a set of queues and topics (with topic subscriptions).

To configure your template for Azure Resource Manager, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-resource-group-adding-resources/

You cannot add the configuration for a service bus with the GUI of Visual Studio but you can do it manually by following this template : https://github.com/sjkp/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/blob/master/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/Templates/DeploymentTemplate.json

Currently, the configuration for service bus is not well documented...